# Slice specific parts out of a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a lot of product descriptions and I have to slice out of them the material details. For example:

```
   var desc = "All over print design SoulCal branding badge 80% Polyester, 20% Elastane Machine washable Keep away from fire."

function materialCutter(desc){
    // some logic here...
    // var material = "80% Polyester, 20% Elastane"

    return material;
}
```

I think I have use the "%" signs, but at this point to be honest I am stuck.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `desc.match(/\d+% \w+/g)`

Comment: You can try to use this RegExp `/\b\d+%\s{1}\w+\s{1}\b/g`

Comment: Is there any rule/ pattern that marks the bwgining of the material section?

Comment: Unless all your material's name are without spaces, this is gonna be a lot harder than you might have thought ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `String.match()` function:

```js
var desc = "All over print design SoulCal branding badge 80% Polyester, 20% Elastane Machine washable Keep away from fire.",
    materials = desc.match(/\b\d+% \w+/g);
 
console.log(materials);
```